# This post was edited with a tag that doesn't seem to exist

Tags: support, tags

I saw [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11086778) in the review queue.

It deletes a tag with no description and only four questions ([serverless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverless)), and adds a tag that doesn't appear to exist ([serverless-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverless-framework)).

Does this tag exist? I searched the tags and synonyms and it doesn't look like it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a tag to exist, it must be attached to at least one question. You can't create one beforehand.

In the case of this edit, the user which proposed it has over 1500 rep, which is the threshold for the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege.

Now, if the edit gets approved, the tag will be created, and you'll be able to edit its wiki. If the edit gets rejected, nothing much will happen.

Maybe the user wants to rename the [serverless] tag to [serverless-framework], which is arguably a more precise name. I couldn't find evidence of other similar edits though.